# Split list range based on input percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x

Split list based an input percentage

Lets assume my list is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

This code has bug, not getting desired results
Code:

```
import argparse

my_list = list(range(1, 11))
print(my_list)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('start_percentage', nargs='?', type=int, default=10)
parser.add_argument('end_percentage', nargs='?', type=int, default=90)

args = parser.parse_args()

start_percent = 100 * int(args.start_percentage / len(my_list))
end_percent = 100 * int(args.end_percentage / len(my_list))

print(start_percent)
print(end_percent)

process_list = my_list[start_percent:end_percent]
print(process_list)
```

Results:

```
input: 0, 100
working 

input: 0, 90
not working 
output: []
expected output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Note:

input list
it is not range, not sorted, and not integers, (Json file has list of elements), I am splitting to process jobs

Comment: What are the specs of the list? always range? sorted? integers?

Comment: it is not range, not sorted, and not integers, (Json file has list of elements), I am splitting to process jobs

Comment: `my_list[start_percent:end_percent]` Do you actually expect `start_percent` and `end_percent` to represent percentage values, out of 100? If so, why do you think it makes sense to use "a number that can range from 0 to 100" to slice the list, regardless of the list length? If not - first off, why did you call it that; and second, did you try to check the values that you get and make sure they make sense?

Comment: I think you really have a math or logic question rather than a programming question. Try to write down, in plain English, a set of steps for converting from the input into slice indices that make sense. Try to follow your steps and see if they work properly. You will need to think logically, and perhaps use reasoning from your high school algebra class.

Comment: It's strange that you print out `start_percent` and `end_percent`, but not finding out `my_list[100:900]` will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are interpreting the percentages incorrectly. To calculate the index on where a percentage occurs:

```
index = (percentage / 100) * length_of_items
```

So, 90% would be:

```
index = (90 / 100) * 10
index = 9
```

Try this:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

start_percentage = 10
end_percentage = 60

start_percent = int((start_percentage / 100) * len(my_list))
end_percent = int((end_percentage / 100) * len(my_list))

print(start_percent)
print(end_percent)

process_list = my_list[start_percent:end_percent]
print(process_list)
```

Output:

```
1
6
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Math skills is very important  to programmers,  Thank you for your help